# trying to add mapping in elasticseach

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-mongo-river

I am trying to add `analyzer` and `mapping` in my elastic search index but I get this error;

`[Error: MapperParsingException[mapping [product]]; nested: MapperParsingException[Analyzer [synonym] not found for field [name]];`

My index name products and type product.my setting -

```
{
  "settings": {
    "products": {
      "analysis":{
        "analyzer":{
          "synonym":{
            "tokenizer": "my_ngram",
            "filter":[
              "synonym"
            ]
          }
        },
        "tokenizer" : {
            "my_ngram" : {
                "type" : "nGram",
                "min_gram" : "2",
                "max_gram" : "3",
                "token_chars": [ "letter", "digit" ]
            }
        },
        "filter":{
          "synonym": {
            "type": "synonym",
            "synonyms_path": "synonyms.txt",
            "ignore_case": "true"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings":{
    "product":{
      "_all":{
        "enabled": true,
      },
      "properties":{
        "name":{
          "type": "string",
           "index": "analyzed",
           "analyzer": "synonym"             
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am using latest version of elastic search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `synonyms.txt` exists, I think this will fix your problem:

```
{
   "settings": {
      "analysis": {
         "analyzer": {
            "synonym": {
               "tokenizer": "my_ngram",
               "filter": [
                  "synonym"
               ]
            }
         },
         "tokenizer": {
            "my_ngram": {
               "type": "nGram",
               "min_gram": "2",
               "max_gram": "3",
               "token_chars": [
                  "letter",
                  "digit"
               ]
            }
         },
         "filter": {
            "synonym": {
               "type": "synonym",
               "synonyms_path": "synonyms.txt",
               "ignore_case": "true"
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "mappings": {
      "product": {
         "_all": {
            "enabled": true
         },
         "properties": {
            "name": {
               "type": "string",
               "index": "analyzed",
               "analyzer": "synonym"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

You don't need the `"products"` entry in `"settings"`.

Comment: i try this but now i got error ** MergeMappingException[Merge failed with failures {[mapper [name] has different index_analyzer]}**

Comment: You'll have to delete the index first.